# HSV color classification with opencv

Tags: opencv, colors

I'm trying to recognize four HSV intervals in a picture, the result images should be made of 0,1,2,3 where these stand for the color index that was recognized.

I'd like to do that using the opencv API as more as I can, in order to reduce execution time and loop overhead. I've tried using inRange and addWeighted but I didn't come up with a functional algorithm. Could you help me?

for example, let's suppose I want to classify

```
110<H<130 && S > 100 && V > 100 as color0
140<H<160 && S > 100 && V > 100 as color1
50<H<70 && S > 100 && V > 100 as color2
```

The problem is that I have to work on all the three channel simultaneously with different intervals, so I suppose that LUT way (1 channel or 3 different channels) isn't the correct way to get a 1D classification output matrix from a 3D input matrix.

Comment: Do you mean that 1) the 4 intervals are preset and fixed for all images, e.g. 0-90, 90-180 and so on, or that they 2) are known ahead of processing and potentially different for each image, or 3) that the intervals are determined according to the content of each picture?

Comment: @MarkSetchell they are known intervals and they are the same for every frame.

Comment: `inRange()` will return an image that is 0 where the values are outside of the specified range, and 255 inside the specified range. Just divide the image by 255, and then add 1, 2, 3, or whatever for which index it is.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry, I forgot to mark it!

Comment: Cool - glad it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I imagine a *Lookup Table* (LUT) would be ideal. Say your ranges were 0-30, 31-78, 79-91 and 92-100, you would make a 256-element LUT where the first 31 entries were zero, the next 48 entries were one and so on. Then call `cv::LUT()`.

The advantage of a LUT is that the output values are simply taken from a table indexed by the Hue value, which means there are not multiple `if` statements per pixel which means the CPU does not stall while determining the branch destination - so it should be very fast.

---

I did some experiments and could not get the built-in `LUT()` function to perform fast for this setup - also had to use `split()` which slowed things down. I used this HSL colour wheel as a test image.

[image]

Here is the code. First it uses `if` statements to process the conditions and times it, and then it repeats the processing but uses 3 LUTs to determine the output values:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/49333257/2836621
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int
main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
   // Open input and check success
   Mat img = cv::imread("start.png",-CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
   if (img.empty()){
      cerr << "ERROR: Failed to open start.png" << endl;
      exit(1);
   }

   // Create HSV version
   Mat hsvMat;
   cv::cvtColor(img,hsvMat,CV_BGR2HSV);

   // Create result Mat, same dimensions as input, and pointer to its data
   Mat result;
   cv::cvtColor(img,result,CV_BGR2GRAY);
   unsigned char* r;

   // Various constants
   const int Sthreshold = 100;
   const int Vthreshold = 100;
   const int Hthreshold[]={110,130,140,160,50,70};

   // Process with if statements and time it
   double t = (double)getTickCount();

   // Iterate over rows and columns of hsvMat
   Vec3b *thisRow;
   for(int j=0;j<hsvMat.rows;++j)
   {
       // Get pointers to input and output rows
       thisRow = hsvMat.ptr<Vec3b>(j);
       r = result.ptr<unsigned char>(j);
       // Iterate over cols
       for(int i=0;i<hsvMat.cols;++i)
       {
          auto H=thisRow[i][0];  // Pick up this pixel's Hue
          auto S=thisRow[i][1];  // Pick up this pixel's Sat
          auto V=thisRow[i][2];  // Pick up this pixel's Value
          // Pre-set output colour to black
          unsigned char v=0;
          if((V>Vthreshold) && (S>Sthreshold)){
             // Set result based on Hue
             if((H>Hthreshold[0]) && (H<Hthreshold[1])){
                v=64;
             } else if((H>Hthreshold[2]) && (H<Hthreshold[3])){
                v=128;
             } else if((H>Hthreshold[4]) && (H<Hthreshold[5])){
                v=192;
             }
          }
          r[i]=v;
       }
   }

   t = (((double)getTickCount() - t)*1000000)/getTickFrequency();
   cout << "Time with if statements: " << t << "us" << std::endl;

   // Write to disk for checking
   imwrite("resultptr.png",result);

   // Now do setup for LUT method

   // Pre-create LUTs for Hue, Saturation, Value
   unsigned char HLUT[256]={0};
   unsigned char SLUT[256]={0};
   unsigned char VLUT[256]={0};
   for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
      if(i>Sthreshold){SLUT[i]=1;}
      if(i>Vthreshold){VLUT[i]=1;}
      if((i>Hthreshold[0]) && (i<Hthreshold[1])){
         HLUT[i]=64;
      } else if((i>Hthreshold[2]) && (i<Hthreshold[3])){
         HLUT[i]=128;
      } else if((i>Hthreshold[4]) && (i<Hthreshold[5])){
         HLUT[i]=192;
      }
   }

   // Process with LUT and time it
   t = (double)getTickCount();

   // Iterate over rows and columns of hsvMat
   for(int j=0;j<hsvMat.rows;++j)
   {
       // Get pointers to input and output rows
       thisRow = hsvMat.ptr<Vec3b>(j);
       r = result.ptr<unsigned char>(j);
       // Iterate over cols
       for(int i=0;i<hsvMat.cols;++i)
       {
          auto H=thisRow[i][0];              // Pick up this pixel's Hue
          auto S=thisRow[i][1];              // Pick up this pixel's Sat
          auto V=thisRow[i][2];              // Pick up this pixel's Value
          r[i]=HLUT[H] * SLUT[S] * VLUT[V];  // Lookup output pixel
       }
   }

   t = (((double)getTickCount() - t)*1000000)/getTickFrequency();
   cout << "Time with LUT: " << t << "us" << std::endl;

   // Write to disk for checking
   imwrite("resultLUT.png",result);
}
```

The result is:

[image]

And the timings on my iMac (with `clang++ -march=native -O3`) are:

```
Time with if statements: 38.429us
Time with LUT: 24.31us
```

If anyone wants to take the code and try alternative methods for the second set of loops, please feel free to try and publish what you get, but keep the first set of loops unchanged for reference.

Comment: sorry, but I was wrong.. I think that I also need to be sure that Saturation and Value are more than a certain fixed amount, in order to correctly classify.. how should I do that? threshold + lut?

Comment: It depends on the numbers. Try and make a little table on a piece of paper with two columns, in the left column put the original values in your image and then try and think what the corresponding entry in the right column would be and then you will have your lookup table. Failing that, click `edit` under your question and put some representative numbers in so I, or others, can assist you further.

Comment: Mark, I updated the question with my doubt! Could you please check it out?

Comment: I couldn't understand your edit, so I redid it how I think you meant - I hope it is correct. You could use a LUT for the Hue as in my answer. Then use a threshold of 100 for saturation so you get zeroes where the Saturation is less than 100 and ones where it is greater. Likewise for Value. Then multiply the 3 Mats together and the calculated Hues will only show up where the Saturation and Value exceed the threshold and will be multiplied by zero elsewhere and will therefore disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However in this way I have to do 1 LUT + 2 Thresholds + Multiplication.. won't be faster to scan with pointers?

Comment: It's hard to say as I don't have your data, nor probably the same CPU or compiler. Try it and measure the time. I guess the LUT part will be faster than using pointers, so maybe do that first, then use pointers to multiply. Once you have it set up with your actual data, and benchmarking code it should be simple enough to compare the methods.

Comment: I tried doing some timings - maybe some other folk would like to take the code and see if they can speed up the second half! ;-)

Comment: Really interesting, thanks Mark! I'll work on it as soon as I can!

Comment: Hi Mark, so, based on your experiment, the DIY lookup was faster than CV::LUT?