# OpenCV LUT to classify pixel color?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm writing a program to classify a color based on their pixel value. Currently there are 5 classes of pixel (each is an object, so class 1 is for example yellow_marker, class 2 is white_post, etc). My current method involved in creating a 3D array with each index representing the range of the input channel (0-255) and the value at that index correspond to the class. While I'm looking at the documentation, I found LUT is implemented in OpenCV, but I can't seems to find  a good documentation on how to use it. As far as I'm understand, the LUT in OpenCV consist of an array (or matrix) consisting of 256 elements (0-255) with each element corresponding to the color value of the input image.

My question is, can OpenCV LUT implementation be used here? But I fail to see how the element of the LUT object which is one color only, can map many pixel that one class can have. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333257/hsv-color-classification-with-opencv) but it also doesn't implemented using LUT function. There's a hint that maybe I need one LUT for each class, but I still fail to see how that could help.

EDIT 1:
I forgot to mention that the input image is using YUV format and here's an example of the range for each classes. The shape can be arbitrary, or even one class having more than one range. That's why I resort to using some sort of lookup table.
[image: YUV color space and range]